# Signup Validation Test didn't change by 1

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

Signup Test Validation not working. Here is the code.

```
    test "valid signup information" do
      get signup_path
          assert_difference 'User.count', 1 do
    post_via_redirect users_path, user:{
                                  name: "Example User",
                                  email: "user@invalid.com",
                                  password: "password",
                                  password_confirmation: "password "
    }
  end
    assert_template 'users/show'
  end
```

Here is the result of Minitest.

```
"User.count" didn't change by 1.
        Expected: 1
          Actual: 0
```

I have done the invalid test, it works fine. the valid path is not working, when i add 1 to the block.

```
   def show
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
  end

  def new
   @user = User.new
  end
  def create
    @user = User.new(user_params)
    if @user.save
      flash[:success] = "Welcome to the app"
      redirect_to user_url(@user)  
    else
      render 'new'
    end
  end
  private 
    def user_params
      params.require(:user).permit(:name, :email, :password, :password_confirmation)
    end
end
```

Updated

Comment: can you post the code snippet for the method that users_path routes to?

Comment: I would suggest adding `puts @user.errors.full_messages` after you called @user.save to see if there are any validation errors.